# (screenshots) Amazon S3 Access Denied even if everything is set as "public"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know, seems like a duplicated question but hear me out.

I have literally set everything as public as possible but still the access is denied.

Account wide settings:
[image]

On the bucket list, the "access" is marked as "public"
[image]

On the bucket level, permissions are set to the public:
[image]

And finally, here's the bucket policy:

```js
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1579091542937",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1579091537693",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME"
        }
    ]
}
```

Like, seriously. What else I can do to allow the users to access the files?

Comment: You may also need to included the objects in the bucket policy. Under resource, try adding `arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*` in addition to the bucket.

Comment: @BenBloom Thanks for your comment. However, the issue was how the files were uploaded. (see my answer)

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:**

The project uses laravel and the solution was to switch `$file->store()` to `$file->storePublicly()`